# Using the trace map to find rational points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a number field and let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve. Let $L/K$ be a finite extension. Consider the trace map
$$
\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}:E(L)\longrightarrow E(K),\qquad \operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(P)=\sum_{\sigma\in G_{L/K}}P^\sigma.   
$$
Why does not the following way of finding $K$-rational points work? Choose any $y\in K$. Calculate $x$ which will lie in some finite extension $L$. Then calculate $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}((x,y))\in E(K)$. Is there a more sophisticated variant?

Comment: Well, it works in the sense that if $L=K$ you have found a rational point. If $[L:K]=3$ then the three points $P^\sigma$ are colinear (same $y$ coordinate) and so sum to $\mathcal O$.